# Is there an Illustrator plugin for better multiple PDF exports? The built-in sucks

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, export

The built-in PDF export and saving options for Illustrator sucks.

Very painful when working with multiple pages and multiple files/documents.

If I use **"Save As", it's suddenly a PDF**, not an AI document.
If I edit it, I have to remember to save back to AI so that it's the latest iteration!

If I use the export function for multiple PDF's (based on artboards in Illustrator)
**all the PDF file sizes are the same**!
regardless of what's in that particular artboard in Illustrator!

Everything would be, like, 64MB even if one artboard/PDF export is blank!

*This is the latest Illustrator CC 2024, you guys. Augh.*

Comment: Hi. When you use Save As, you should check what format you are saving it in.  I can't reproduce the problem. A document doesn't "suddenly" become a PDF, unless I save it as a PDF. If I save it as an AI, it is saved as an AI file.

Comment: No, I mean my problem is saving it as multiple PDFs.
Illustrator just makes it hard to do it.

Okay, I suddenly have an idea for the Adobe team: instead of an AI "suddenly becoming a PDF" on "Save As", there should be an option where it will save a PDF but remain an AI file as I'm editing it.

(Editing a PDF presents problems in Illustrator, especially in cross-machine situations).

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding the problem. Are you asking how to manage exporting a PDF (without Illustrator capabilities) to save on file size and saving the working file in one export?

Comment: Illustrator makes it fuzzy what happens when you save a file. The whole idea of saving as PDF with "preserved editing capabilities" is crazy! Gives you PDFs with AI files inside. In my opinion it shouldn't be possible to "save" a PDF. It should instead be "exported" to distinguish between working file and final file for production/distribution.

Comment: You can fix this by making sure you always save your AI before saving as a PDF.

Answer (score 4):

`File > Save a Copy...` is your friend.

Don't `Save As..` for a PDF.. `Save A Copy...` for a PDF. 
<sub><kbd>Option/Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> rather than <kbd>Command/Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd></sub>

This, leaves the open document as the original .ai file and merely saves a PDF to disk. 
<sub>(Similar to how InDesign *exports* PDFs as separate files rather than replacing the open document.)</sub>

---

I *absolutely* agree that saving as a PDF should *not* make the open document then the PDF. But it's been this way since.. well.. AI10 I think. No hopes of it being addressed soon.